# Java Class name getting garbled in SWT/JFace TableViewer

Tags: swt, jface, tableviewer

I'm developing a RCP application that contains a `TableViewer`. This is my first attempt at a RCP app, so sorry if this is a silly question.
I'm having trouble with the content provider's `inputChanged` method. The input objects in the table are `Strings`. Here is the method, as I have so far (Scenario is a class in my app, with a `displayData` method):

```
public void inputChanged(Viewer v, Object oldInput, Object newInput) {
    if (newInput != null) {
        String s = (String)newInput;
        Scenario.displayData(s);
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following Exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.String; cannot be cast to java.lang.String

How did the class name get garbled? I tried printing out the class name, using `newInput.getClass().getName()`, and still got the garbled version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "[L" means it's an array of strings.

Comment: Then apparently I'm going about this incorrectly. I'm trying to get only the string associated with the highlighted input value, but apparently it's getting the whole list, and only at startup, not when I click on a value. Thanks for clearing that up.